# Creating template links in js

Tags: python, django

I'm creating microblogging site and I have a questiong about creating links. I have model Post with content_post - textField. When someone write @username or #tag then I want to create links there to user profile or specific tag. I wrote js script which looping over content words and when word contains @ or # then it replace word to `<a href=/profile/${userId}` and same for tags. It's working, but is it acceptable if I work with django? I mean good practices etc. I know it probably should be `<a href={% url 'profile' user %}`, but what if i'm out of variable scope?